# An existence of exponential function for a Lie algebra.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group (given by a matrix). Let $\frak g$ be its Lie algebra.

I would like to know if the following is true.

"Let $X$ be a matrix in $\frak g$. Then $\gamma(t)=\exp(tX)$ is a curve in $G$."

Here $\exp(Y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{Y^n}{n!}$ for a matrix $Y$.

Comment: the matrix exponential converges for any matrix, so it certain converges for a subset of matrices. How do you characterize $G$ here ? For example, if $G = GL(n)$ then $X \in gl(n)$ is clearly such that $exp(tX) \in G$ as $det(exp(tX))=exp(Trace(tX))$ which is nonzero...

Comment: I hope you didn't mind, but I substituted $\frak g$ for $g$, since many books use the gothic letters for Lie algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ODE on $G$:
$$ \gamma^{-1} \dot \gamma = X , \qquad \gamma(0) = I .$$
Then by definition, this is a well defined equation on the Lie group.  This is because $X$ is an element of the tangent space of the identity, and $\dot \gamma$ is an element of the tangent space at $\gamma$, and pre-multiplication by $\gamma^{-1}$ maps the tangent space at $\gamma$ to the tangent space at $I$.

So if the Lie group happens to be a subgroup of the $n\times n$ matrices, it makes no difference - the solution to this ODE, if it exists, stays inside the group.

But the solution to this ODE is given by $\gamma(t) = \exp(tX)$.

(You can use post-multiplication as well $\dot \gamma \gamma^{-1} = X$.)

---

Another way to see it.  For any $X \in \frak g$, and $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, there is a function $h(\epsilon)$ so that $I + \epsilon X + h(\epsilon) \in G$, where $h(\epsilon) = o(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Now consider $\left(I+\dfrac tn X + h\left(\dfrac tn\right)\right)^n$.  This is a product of elements of $G$, and hence is in $G$.  But this converges to $\exp(tX)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Could you tell me why $h(\epsilon)$ exists?

Comment: So $X$ is in the tangent space of $G$ at the identity.  That is, there exists a function $u:[-1,1]\to G$ satisfying $u(0) = I$ such that $\dot u(0) = X$.  By the definition of derivative, we have $u(\epsilon) = I + \epsilon X + h(\epsilon)$, where $h(\epsilon) = o(\epsilon)$.  And by construction, we have $u(\epsilon) \in G$.